# Google adwords conversion tracking integration in joomla php file

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, cdata, google-ads-api

I am trying to include a piece of code from Google Conversion Tracking into my business contact from which is based on Jomla. The code should be integrated once the Thank you message appears but unfortunately I am very unexperienced with javascript and php. Could someone please give me a hand having these two pieces of code combined?

Thank you very much, James

Code Jomla

```
            //<![CDATA[

        <!--

        window.addEvent('load', function() {

            changeCaptcha(".$this->profile->id.",0);\n".($use_ajax?"resetSubmit(".$this->profile->id.");\n":"")."

            if($(typeof SqueezeBox!='undefined' && 'system-message')) {

                SqueezeBox.initialize();

                SqueezeBox.open($('system-message'), {

                    handler: 'adopt',

                    size: {x: $('system-message').offsetWidth+30, y: $('system-message').offsetHeight+30}

                });

            }

        });

        //-->

        //]]>
```

Code Google:

```
    <!-- Google Code for Contact Form Conversion Page -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 1033530737;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "2";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "A8yvCJrs4AIQtHey6hT";
    var google_conversion_value = 0;
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
    </script>
    <noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
    <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" 
    src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1033530737/?                label=A8yvCJrs4AIQtHey6hT&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
    </div>
    </noscript>
```

Comment: What are you using for your contact form?

Answer (score 0):

It has a joomla plugin that includes the conversion code on the default page of the contact: http://www.joomlaadwordsconversion.com/